# getLastRow() return me empty value

Tags: google-apps-script

I got a script who used to work perfectly but since this morning he doesn't work anymore. This script is based on the use of `getLastRow()` which is supposed to return me the value from the last row of the second column of my sheet.

so here is what doesn't work :

```
var test = overview.getRange(overview.getLastRow(),2).getValue()
```

Here is what's working :

```
var test = overview.getRange(360,2).getValue()
```

I'm doing a log when running these variables in a function. As I said the first one doesn't return me anything, the second one return me the value wanted.

What could make `getLastRow()` doesn't work ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried saving the returned last row to a variable and showing that in the log?  `var lastRow = overview.getLastRow();` And then maybe using the variable in your line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is 360 really the last row of your whole sheet? Maybe formulas that have been copied are disrupting. Check if you have any values or formulas past row 360 in all columns of the sheet.

Remember:getLastRow gets the last row of the whole sheet, not the specified range.